# Adding parentClass as target to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector

I've a UIButton `likeButton`, which will call `likeBtnClicked` on `.TouchUpinside`

```
likeButton.addTarget(self.superview, action: "likeBtnClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

This works fine but with warning

> "No method declared with Objective-C selector".

If `likeButton` is implemented in one class (say MyClass) then I would have replaced it with

```
likeButton.addTarget(Myclass, action: #selector(Myclass.likeBtnClicked), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But how to make it work for multiple classes(viewControllers) which wants to use 'likeButton' without any warnings?? This question holds same for UITapGestureRecognizer too.

Here is the sample code:

```
import Foundation

class SubClass: UIView {

   var likeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,50))

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       addSubview(likeButton)
       likeButton.addTarget(self.superview, action: "likeBtnClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}

class SuperClassA: UIView {

   let viewHavingBtn = SubClass(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,500))

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       addSubview(viewHavingBtn)
   }

   func likeBtnClicked(sender: AAButton) {
       print(sender.tag)
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}

class SuperClassB: UIView {

   let viewHavingBtn = SubClass(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,500))

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       addSubview(viewHavingBtn)
   }

   func likeBtnClicked(sender: AAButton) {
       print(sender.tag)
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use a delegate pattern. It is a bad idea for your UiView to assume that the superview implements a particular method.

Comment: Thanks :) @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1] declare a UIButton object in the superclass

2] initialize that button and add target to that button in super class initialization method

3] define action method for touch event in the superclass

4] add that button as a subview in the subclass to display button

5] override button action method implementation from the superclass in the subclass where you want to handle button touches.